# Internet goes out in Windows 7 until adapter is disabled/enabled

Tags: windows-7, internet

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate x64. Periodically the internet goes completely out. I have to disable and then re-enable the adapter to get it working again. Its not a DHCP issue as I use a static address. Its not my DNS servers because I use OpenDNS. None of the other computers on my network do this which is a mix of Windows 7, Windows XP, wired, and wireless. I have also tried reinstalling Windows which didn't fix the issue.

I've also recently moved apartments and nothing hardware wise has changed. Just my ISP. Could it possibly be my ISP?

Comment: Yeah I also have this problem. it started when I installed VMWare Workstation because the VMWare adapters where overpowering my WLAN card. I uninstalled them and then they stopped connecting by default, but now I'm having to disable/enable the adapter like you.

Comment: I have this too! But in XP it NEVER happens, so this can't be related to hardware problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the NIC card may be on it's last limbs. Before ditching the hardware though...

- Try updating its drivers
- Try reseating it if it's a PCI card
- If you have another NIC card on hand, try it instead to confirm the NIC is the problem

If you intend to replace it, and it is built into your motherboard, you don't need to replace the entire board. You can [buy a PCI gigabit NIC for very little these days](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833180026):

[image]

Just ensure you have a spare PCI slot!

Comment: No more PCI slots but I did have a Gigabit USB LAN adapter lying around and so far no problems.

Answer (score -4):

This is a Windows 7 bug.  I has nothing to do with faulty hardware.  It happens on numerous brand new computers on many different ethernet connections.  I have a laptop where this happens all the time, computer is brand new, Linux runs on same computer with no problems.  There is a bug in the device management for internal ethernet device.  Disable/enable always resolves problem.  There is no better way at the moment until Windows is repaired.

Comment: Do you have any sources for these claims? Why did the new NIC fix the issue then? I think you are just randomly bashing windows....